# SSRS 2016: Report Delivery Extension to send report email via MicrosoftGraph&AzureIdentity, but error in assembly version of Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, microsoft-graph-mail, azure-identity

Microsoft announced the expiration of Basic Authentication in Exchange Online except STMP AUTH, but no guarantee on using it for long term. So, I decide to start the change with our Reports delivery in SSRS 2016 which mainly via SMTP email right now.

After reading many sources, I found that SSRS has Report Delivery Extension which we can build assembly to customize new Delivery Method, and from here I can send the Report Email through Microsoft Graph & Azure Identity.

[Link of delivery extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/delivery-extension/delivery-extensions-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)

In the Project, I added Nuget Package of:

- Microsoft Graph package version 4.47
- Azure Identity version 1.8
  the VS automatically add other dependencies to project and I can build the project successfully without any Warnings or Error

[image: Project build successfully]

However, deploying the assembly to SSRS, after the subscription runs, I got the error in the log as following:

**notification!WindowsService_0!59ac!11/18/2022-16:42:08:: i INFO: Notification 27e69a92-12b9-4ab8-984f-d5910af77de7 completed.  Success: True, Status: Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

I check carefully the dependency of other assembly in nuget website, but nothing indicates that I'm using wrong version. The Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll file is copied to Bin folder of ReportServer.

I tried to update the Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll file with version 4.46.0 in nuget (ignore the dependencies), but another assembly version mismatch comes up:

**notification!WindowsService_0!4d94!11/17/2022-23:59:03:: i INFO: Notification b82bb214-3880-4f80-857b-cdf42cde8ff0 completed.  Success: True, Status: Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

And now, I could not find the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll with version 4.0.4.
I can only find version 4.0.0 or 4.3 above.

Now I'm stuck here.

Does anyone have experience on this?
How can I bypass this dependency check?

I even try to downgrade version of Azure.Identity version to lower one, but still stop at the System.Diagnostics version 4.0.4

Then I create a Console Application which I just send a test email with all latest version of assembly Azure.Identity and Microsoft.Graph on the same server (same .Net Framework 4.7.2 and same firewall configuration). It can be sent sucessfully.

I'm in doubt that SSRS 2016 has any assembly confliction which point to lower version of those assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, but with building an add-on for Act! for Windows. My code works outside Act! in a standalone .NET 4.7.2 app, but I get the exact same conflict as described above when loaded within Act!. That said, Act! itself doesn't even use Microsoft.Identity.Client (that dll is not part of it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).